# How to test the order of multiple list items in Flutter / Dart?

Tags: flutter, testing, dart

**Intro**

We have a `ListView` named OrganizationList which contains a `ListTile` widget for every item. We use a `Text` widget to display the name of the organization inside the `ListTile`.

We would like to test if the organization name is displayed correctly and in the correct order.

**Our current solution**

We have the following assertions:

```
var organizationA = find
    .descendant(
        of: find.byType(OrganizationList),
        matching: find.byKey(
            Key('0'),
        ),
     )
     .evaluate()
     .first
     .widget as Text;
expect(textOrganization.data, 'organization-a');

var organizationB = find
    .descendant(
        of: find.byType(OrganizationList),
        matching: find.byKey(
            Key('1'),
        ),
     )
     .evaluate()
     .first
     .widget as Text;
expect(textOrganization.data, 'organization-b');
```

This feels like a very cumbersome way of testing if the right label is shown for the list items. But I fail to find a more elegant way.

**Question**

What is a more elegant way in Flutter / Dart to assert both the content of a list item and the order of all items?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to get elements from List and verify is `widgetList`, which gives a list of elements of whatever data type we have provided.

**Sample test:**

*Problem: Verify the second item from List*

```
const List<String> listString = [
  "Ac",
  "Fuel Sensor",
  "Power",
  "Panic",
  "Camera",
  "Relay",
  "Duty Button",
  "Other"
];
```

**Test:**

```
testWidgets('Listview item verify', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      await tester.pumpWidget(ListViewApp());
     /// Verify OrganizationIte sequence to get and verify title. 
      OrganizationItem item = tester
          .widgetList<OrganizationItem>(find.byType(OrganizationItem))
          .elementAt(2);
      String data = item.title;
      expect("Power", data);
    });
```

**App Code:**

```
 class ListViewApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Checked Listview',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Checked Listview'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> _list = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {
      for (int i = 0; i < listString.length; i++) {
        _list.add('${listString[i]}');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Listview Sample'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
          return OrganizationItem(
            title: _list[index],
          );
        },
        itemCount: _list.length,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OrganizationItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const OrganizationItem({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(this.title),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With my solution you can check if a ListItemWidget at specific position and text is visible(or not):

```
void checkPosition(int index, SomeObj obj, {bool isOnPosition = true}) {
  final listItemFinder = find.byType(ListItemWidget);
  final listItem = listItemFinder.evaluate().isEmpty
      ? null
      : listItemFinder.at(index);
  if (listItem == null) {
    if (isOnPosition) {
      fail('List not found');
    }
    return;
  }
  final positionText = find.text(obj.text);
  expect(find.descendant(of: listItem, matching: positionText),
      isOnPosition ? findsOneWidget : findsNothing);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a `for` loop:

```
// This is for saving a reference to the ListTile from the previous iteration
ListTile? previousListTile;

for (int j = 0; j < aListOfModels.length; j++) {
  final organizationA = find.descendant(
      of: find.byType(OrganizationList),
      matching: find.byKey(
          Key('0'),
      ),
   );
  // This is important to show the invisible late elements
  await widgetTester.scrollUntilVisible(organizationA, tryToFindTheSuitableDelta);

  // I suppose that organizationA finds a ListTile widget
  ListTile currentListTile = widgetTester.widget<ListTile>(organizationA);
  /* 
  Make your expectations about the content as you like
  ....
  ...
  */

  // To expect about the order, do the following:
  final listTileWidgetList = widgetTester
      .widgetList<ListTile>(find.byType(ListTile))
      .toList();
  
  if (j > 0) {
    // Expect that the currentListTile is the first next ListTile of the previousListTile
    expect(listTileWidgetList.indexOf(currentListTile),
      equals(listTileWidgetList.indexOf(previousListTile!) + 1));
  }
  // To allow you to make your expectation about the order in the next iteration
  previousListTile = currentListTile;
}
```